# What is the Waitress/The Envoy reference in J. Ringo's "Claws That Catch"?

Tags: claws-that-catch, voyage-of-the-space-bubble

In *Claws That Catch*, Eric and his new bride, Brooke, are talking about her new job as a waitress. She's having trouble with guys hitting on her.

Eric reassures her no one really expects to go home with the waitress except "The Envoy". I do NOT get that reference. Anyone? Is it a music reference? Something stupid obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a music reference, which, unfortunately, is a bit convoluted...

It comes from Warren Zevon's *Lawyers, Guns and Money*:

Lyrics explain the waitress bit:

> I went home with the waitress
>
> the way I always do
>
> How was I to know
>
> she was with the
>
> Russians too?

However, to explain the *The Envoy* one has to go to another song, which is another hit of Zevon's - *The Envoy*...

Sometimes Author's tastes end up his book's Protagonist tastes... And Warren Zevon is mentioned in different works of J.R. often. ;-)

Well, oftenish.